# pg_dump - table dependencies when using --table

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html) says this when using `-t table`:

> Note When -t is specified, pg_dump makes no attempt to dump any other
>   database objects that the selected table(s) might depend upon.
>   Therefore, there is no guarantee that the results of a specific-table
>   dump can be successfully restored by themselves into a clean database.

However, when the table has a sequence, and the `owned by` for the sequence is set to the table, it is included in the dump.

Shouldn't it be excluded according to this part of the documentation? (If so, why are sequences exceptions?)

What kind of database objects are going to be excluded in `-t table` mode then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pg_dump -t will dump the definition of foreign key constraints.  But will not dump the definition (or data) of the table which that constraint points to.

Similarly, if you have a check constraint which uses a function, the definition of the function will not get dumped.

I don't know the thought process behind dumping sequences.  That does seem like a documentation bug.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence and the last sequence number used be necessary to assure the logical integrity of the object upon restoration? If it was not needed, it could be dropped.